# How to make the process run while the button is pressed?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I use:
  - Win 7x64;
  - Access - 2016;

I try to solve my problem with the following code.
**Form1**

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public statusBool As Boolean
Public numProc As Integer

' `Button pressed`.
Private Sub btnStart_Click()
        numProc = 0
        statusBool = True

        Call Process(statusBool, numProc)

End Sub

' Process
Public Sub Process(statusBool As Boolean, numProc As Integer)
        If statusBool = True Then

           Me.txtProcessFrm = "ProcessNum - " & numProc + 1
            Call SleepFor(1000)  '1 seconds delay

           Call Process(statusBool, numProc)
        End If

End Sub

'
Private Sub btnStart_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    statusBool = False
    numProc = 0
    Call Process(statusBool, numProc)
End Sub


Public Sub SleepFor(ByVal MilliSeconds As Long)
    Sleep MilliSeconds
End Sub
```

**Module1**

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

**Question**
Will my solution be correct for this task or are there simpler ways to solve this problem?

[image]

**Update_1**
The code does not start.
I get an error `Sub or Function not defined`.
[image]

**Update_2**
Module `Module1`.
Replaced `Private` to `Public`.
It was
 `Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)`

It became
`Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)`

**Problem.**
When I click the button `btnStart_Click` the file hangs

**Update_3**
Modified Process (statusBool As Boolean, numProc As Integer)
It became.

```
 ' Process
    Public Sub Process(statusBool As Boolean, numProc As Integer)
            If statusBool = True Then
                Do
                        Sleep 1000
                        DoEvents
                Loop Until Me.txtProcessFrm = "ProcessNum - " & numProc + 1

               Call Process(statusBool, numProc)
            End If

    End Sub
```

**Problem.**
It seems the pause works, but the logic itself does not work.
In other words, the text field is not filled with text.
If you release the button, the cycle continues to work.

Comment: *Will my solution be correct for this task* - did you run it?

Comment: `Sleep` stops the thread from executing. I'm guessing you're looking for `DoEvents`. I'm not entirely clear on why you're spinning a process while the mouse button is held down though.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon Updated the question.

Comment: @Comintern I just want to practice to implement the "process works while the button is pressed" logic.
I made the decision according to the principle as I see it.
I have no experience in this matter. If you offer your version, I will be grateful.
Updated the question.

Comment: `Sleep` halts the UI thread (the only thread available to VBA). That's by design... it's a feature, not a bug. If you don't want to sleep, don't invoke `Sleep`.

Comment: @Comintern Sorry, I do not quite understand English. I did, as I understand it. The solution does not work.
`Update_3`

Comment: You have to take the [`Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep) out *completely*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chain of event for clicking a button follows as this.

```
MouseDown → MouseUp → Click → DblClick → Click
```

In your code, the loop will never stop because your statusBool will always be true causing infinite loop and that's probably why it's hanging even if you release the mosue.

you can however try this mouse down => mouse up:

```
Private Sub btnStart_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    statusBool = True
    Call Process(0)
End Sub

Private Sub btnStart_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    statusBool = False
End Sub

Public Sub Process(numProc As Integer)
    If statusBool Then
        numProc = numProc + 1
        Me.txtProcessFrm = "ProcessNum - " & numProc
        Sleep 1000
        DoEvents

        Call Process(numProc)
    End If
End Sub
```

more here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.commandbutton.click